# Partition a sequence of disjunctions in Scalaz

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

What is the best way to partition `Seq[A \/ B]` into `(Seq[A], Seq[B])` using Scalaz?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a method: `separate` [defined](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/MonadPlus.scala#L24) in MonadPlus. This typeclass is a combination a Monad with PlusEmpty (generalized Monoid). So you need to define instance for `Seq`:

1) MonadPlus[Seq]

```
implicit val seqmp = new MonadPlus[Seq] {
  def plus[A](a: Seq[A], b: => Seq[A]): Seq[A] = a ++ b
  def empty[A]: Seq[A] = Seq.empty[A]
  def point[A](a: => A): Seq[A] = Seq(a)
  def bind[A, B](fa: Seq[A])(f: (A) => Seq[B]): Seq[B] = fa.flatMap(f)
}
```

Seq is already monadic, so `point` and `bind` are easy, `empty` and `plus` are monoid operations and `Seq` is a [free monoid](http://blog.higher-order.com/blog/2013/08/20/free-monads-and-free-monoids/)

2) Bifoldable[\/]

```
implicit val bife = new Bifoldable[\/] {
    def bifoldMap[A, B, M](fa: \/[A, B])(f: (A) => M)(g: (B) => M)(implicit F: Monoid[M]): M = fa match {
      case \/-(r) => g(r)
      case -\/(l) => f(l)
    }

    def bifoldRight[A, B, C](fa: \/[A, B], z: => C)(f: (A, => C) => C)(g: (B, => C) => C): C = fa match {
      case \/-(r) => g(r, z)
      case -\/(l) => f(l, z)
    }
  }
```

Also easy, standard folding, but for type constructors with two parameters.

Now you can use separate:

```
val seq: Seq[String \/ Int] = List(\/-(10), -\/("wrong"), \/-(22), \/-(1), -\/("exception"))
scala> seq.separate
res2: (Seq[String], Seq[Int]) = (List(wrong, number exception),List(10, 22, 1))
```

**Update**

Thanks to [Kenji Yoshida](https://stackoverflow.com/users/605582/kenji-yoshida), there [is](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.1.0-M3/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Either.scala#L373) a Bitraverse[\/], so you need only MonadPlus.

And a simple solution using `foldLeft`:

```
seq.foldLeft((Seq.empty[String], Seq.empty[Int])){ case ((as, ai), either) =>
  either match {
    case \/-(r) => (as, ai :+ r)
    case -\/(l) => (as :+ l, ai)
  }
}
```

Comment: There's actually a bug in 7.0.3/4 where `.separate` isn't available.

Comment: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.1.0-M3/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/MonadPlus.scala#L24 please use 7.1.0-M3

Comment: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.1.0-M3/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Either.scala#L373 There is Bifoldable[\/]. Bitraverse is subtype of Bifoldable